# Grouping data by quarter but adding a cut off date to account for zero values

Tags: r, grouping, zoo

I have the following dataset that are being grouped by quarter. The issue is that after Q3 2021 i.e. in Q4 2021 and Q1 2022 there hasn't been any cases so no dates in original data to look at and group them and put zero for them. Is there a way to put a cut off date when grouping data so it would account for such quarters?
dput(test_date) is as follow:

```
structure(list(X = 1:31, test_quarter = c("2014 Q2", "2014 Q3", 
"2014 Q4", "2015 Q1", "2015 Q2", "2015 Q3", "2015 Q4", "2016 Q1", 
"2016 Q2", "2016 Q3", "2016 Q4", "2017 Q1", "2017 Q2", "2017 Q3", 
"2017 Q4", "2018 Q1", "2018 Q2", "2018 Q3", "2018 Q4", "2019 Q1", 
"2019 Q2", "2019 Q3", "2019 Q4", "2020 Q1", "2020 Q2", "2020 Q3", 
"2020 Q4", "2021 Q1", "2021 Q2", "2021 Q3", "2021 Q4"), cases = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 38L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 6L, 20L, 32L, 42L, 
26L, 18L, 25L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -31L))


library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  mutate(test_date = lubridate::dmy(test_date),
         test_quarter = zoo::as.yearqtr(test_date)+0.25) %>% # 0.25 added to make the code put the end day of quarter instead of first day of quarter##
  count(test_quarter, name = 'cases') %>%
  tidyr::complete(test_quarter = seq(min(test_quarter), max(test_quarter), 1/4), 
                  fill = list(cases = 0))
```

This is how the data look-like after grouping. The only way I can think of is to ask the code to consider the end date as end of March 2022 while the recoded data are till July 2017:

[image]

any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Hank, could you please share your data using `dput(test_date)`?

Comment: Many thanks @Quinten. Added the dput( test_date). Basically want the code to add the next two quarters and put zero values for "cases" for these two quarters.

Answer (score 0):

We assume that the question is how to sum the cases by year and quarter extending it by two quarters with zero cases.

Convert `dataset` to a zoo object `z` aggregating cases and then use `merge.zoo` to append two zero cases giving zoo object `cases`.  Either use `cases` as is or else convert it back to data frame using `fortify.zoo`.

(If the input were the ending year and quarter to extend to rather than the number of quarters to extend by we could replace `end(z) + 1:2/4` with `seq(end(z) + 1/4, as.yearqtr("2022 Q2"), 1/4)` .)

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(dataset[-1], FUN = as.yearqtr, aggregate = sum)
cases <- merge(z, zoo(, end(z) + 1:2/4), fill = 0)

fortify.zoo(cases, name = "yearqtr")
```

giving:

```
   yearqtr cases
1  2014 Q2     1
2  2014 Q3     0
3  2014 Q4     0
4  2015 Q1     0
5  2015 Q2     0
6  2015 Q3     0
7  2015 Q4    38
8  2016 Q1     4
9  2016 Q2     2
10 2016 Q3     8
11 2016 Q4     9
12 2017 Q1    13
13 2017 Q2     6
14 2017 Q3    20
15 2017 Q4    32
16 2018 Q1    42
17 2018 Q2    26
18 2018 Q3    18
19 2018 Q4    25
20 2019 Q1    11
21 2019 Q2     5
22 2019 Q3     4
23 2019 Q4     4
24 2020 Q1     3
25 2020 Q2     1
26 2020 Q3     2
27 2020 Q4     2
28 2021 Q1     2
29 2021 Q2     3
30 2021 Q3     0
31 2021 Q4     1
32 2022 Q1     0
33 2022 Q2     0
```

Comment: Thanks G.Grothendiek , I am not sure where in the above code I should add this?

Comment: This replaces all the code in the question.  It takes dataset as an input and produces the output shown.  read.zoo converts dataset to a zoo series summing the counts at the same time and also converting the index to yearqtr all in one statement.  Then the merge appends the 2 additional quarters.  (See the help pages of the relevant functions and the vignettes in the package for more info.)